# Pointwise fofibrations in $\mathcal{C}^I$ as saturation of a set

Tags: simplicial-stuff, model-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a cofibrantly generated simplicial model category, say with its set of cofibrations $\beta$-saturated and generated by a set of $\beta$-small morphisms $\mathcal{M}_0$, and $I$ a small category.

For $i\in I$ we have adjunctions $F_i: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}^I: G_i$ by 
\begin{align*}
G_iX = X(i); && \& && F_iD(j) = \bigsqcup_{I(i,j)} D
\end{align*}
for $X \in \mathcal{C}^I, D \in \mathcal{C}, j\in I$, with obvious action on morphisms.

One can show:

- If $A \to B \in \mathcal{M}_0$, then $F_iA \to F_iB$ is a pointwise cofibration in $\mathcal{C}^I$, i.e. all $G_jF_iA \to G_jF_iB$ are cofibrations in $\mathcal{C}$
- $\mathcal{M} := \{ \text{pointwise cofibrations of } \mathcal{C}^I \}$ is $\beta$-saturated

Hence it follows that the $\beta$-saturation of $\{F_iA \to F_iB \mid i\in I, A \to B \in \mathcal{M}_0\}$ is contained in $\mathcal{M}$. My question is, do we have equality and why? Goerss & Jardine claim we do ( Exmpl. II.6.9), but I don't see why.

Comment: Apparently I have misread the statement in Goerss & Jardine. I'm guessing now we probably don't have equality per se.

Comment: Goerss and Jardine only claim inclusion, not equality.  The β-saturation of the smaller class coincides with the class of projective cofibrations, which is much smaller than the class of injective cofibrations.